# Is it possible to set GPG key expiration time shorter than one day (say, an hour)?

Tags: gnupg

In my project, we want to test how our product behaves when the GPG key expires. So we want the key to expire in a really short time in order to repeat the test frequently.

Actually, the prompt message when generating the key clearly indicates that the minimal unit of expiration is "day":

```
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
```

But I still want to ask the question out just in case there is something that meets my need: **Is it possible to set GPG key expiration time shorter than one day (say, an hour, or even minutes)?**

If there is no such a way, I'll need to figure out how to repeat our test without having to wait for a whole day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is only documented in the [source code](https://dev.gnupg.org/source/gnupg/browse/master/common/gettime.c;7922e2dd1c7eee48a8a2cf4799827942489ddd0f$359-362), but you can just enter the datetime at the `Key is valid for? (0)` prompt using the form `yyyymmddThhmmss`.

For example, to set the expiry to 8 March 2099 at 9:34 AM (UTC), you would enter `20990308T093400`. The time zone of your input is always interpreted as UTC, although you will see the confirmation in your local time zone, e.g. `Key expires at Fri Mar  8 10:34:00 2099 +01`.

As of version 2.1.20, you can also [append a `Z` to the datetime to explicitly denote UTC](https://dev.gnupg.org/rG0e5bd473a07f188615c4fce26b73bb452d689d68), e.g. `20190308T093400 Z`, but no other time zones are supported for entry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it on Ubuntu 18.04 with gpg 2.2.4. When I entered "20190308T093400", it output a message "Key expires at Fri 08 Mar 2019 04:34:00 AM EST" followed by "invalid value". Then it kept prompting me with "Key is valid for? (0)". I also tried append "Z" to the date but got the same "invalid value" message. I guess the `yyyymmddThhmmss` is only for internal use? Or maybe I was not using it the right way?

Comment: Try using a datetime that isn't in the past! "20190308T093400" was in the future when I was writing this post, but it's past now. I'll update the answer to use some future datetime

Comment: Aha! I did overlook that! I just tried with gpg 2.2.4 on my Mac, and it works like a miracle! Yes, a time in the future is needed!